# Proving that a functional is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal A_r$ be all the functions analytic in the open disk $D_r\in\mathbb C$, centred at the origin and of radius $r$, that have finite supremum over $D_r$.

I have a functional $\Theta:\mathcal A_r \to \mathbb C$. I have proved that for any $f_\mu \subset \mathcal A_r$ with $\mu \in V\subset\mathbb C^n$ such that $\|f_\mu\|_{\mathcal A_r} \le M$ for some $M>0$, the function $\Theta(f_\mu)$ is analytic in $V$ for any natural $n$.

The way I get this is by constructing a sequence $\{\Theta_m(f_\mu)\}_{m\ge0}$ and show that for $f_\mu$ as above the sequence converges uniformly. The only thing I really need to prove the uniform convergence is the uniform bound of $f_\mu$.

So is this enough to conclude that $\Theta$ is an analytic functional on $\mathcal A_r$ or do I need something more?

EDIT: Meaning of $f_\mu$.

Let $\nu\in U\subset \mathbb C$, and let $f:U\times D_r \to \mathbb C$ be analytic, such that $|f(\nu,z)|\le M$ for all $\nu \in U$ and $z\in D_r$.

An other way of looking at such function is as a subset of $\mathcal A_r$. In this case we write $f_\nu:D_r \to \mathbb C$ analytic and uniformly bounded for all $\nu\in U$. In this case $f_\nu$ is an 1 dimensional subset of $\mathcal A_r$.

I use the latter viewpoint. So when I write $f_\mu:D_r \to \mathbb C$ analytic for all $\mu\in V\subset\mathbb C^n$, I mean that we have an analytic function $f:V\times D_r \to \mathbb C$ and we treat the first $n$ variables as parameters. This gives us an $n$ dimensional subset of $\mathcal A_r$.

Comment: The functional is it linear, continuous? The functions take value in what space? What is $\mu$ doing? Below there is a sequence of (linear?) functionals?

Comment: No, it is not linear. When I write $f_\mu$ I mean a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal A_r$, which is parametrized by $\mu$. Unfortunately I haven't proved continuity yet. Can continuity be derived from the analyticity on finite dimensional subsets?

Comment: What is the relation with the sequence $\Theta_m$? And do you mean that given a finite number of $f_1,...,f_n$ then $\Theta(c_1f_1+\cdots+c_nf_n)$ is analytic in $c=(c_1,...,c_n) \in {\Bbb C}^n$ (the whole space)?

Comment: I added an explanation for my notation. I'm sorry for being unclear. I hope it is clarified now. The functionals $\Theta_m$ should be thought as non-linear integrations (actually they are multiple convolutions defined inductively).

Comment: I forgot to answer your question. Given a a finite number of $f_i$'s then the $\Theta(c_1 f_1+\dots+c_n f_n)$ is analytic for all $c=(c_1,\dots,c_n)\in V$ if $V$ is open and bounded.